# Verificar posiciones de un array y reemplazarlos con el algoritmo optimo

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Buenas noches,

El problema con el siguiente pedazo de código es que necesito que se guarden las posiciones de todos los valores repetidos que se encuentren, por ejemplo:

**Haciendo uso del algoritmo FIFO**

`marcos = [4,1,2]`   `cadena = [5,1,2,3,4,5]`

El primero que entra es el primero en salir por lo tanto, e**l 5 reemplaza al 4**, pero cuando se repite un valor no se debe de reemplazar dado que dicho valor ya se encuentra en el array `marcos`. 
Siguiendo con la lógica del  algoritmo este debería de saltar los valores repetidos que este caso serian `1,2` y continuar `[5,3,4]` y por lo tanto el 5 tampoco sería reemplazado.

Entonces en mi `array` de **"repetidos"** debe de guardarse `[1,2]` que son las posiciones correspondientes de los elementos que se repiten del array marcos.

```
for(var i = 0; i < marcos.length; i++){
        if(marcos[i] == cadena[i]){
            var repetido = cadena.indexOf(cadena[i]);
            array.push(repetido);
            cadena.splice(repetido , 1);
        }

        if(array.length > 0){
            //aca iria el 
            marcos.splice(array[i] , 1 , cadena[i])
           //y luego se elimina el elemento del array para eguir con el proceso de forma normal
        }else{
            marcos.splice(i, 1, cadena[i]);
        }

    }
```

**Haciendo uso del algoritmo óptimo**

La diferencia de este con el FIFO es que reemplaza el valor más lejano.

```
marcos [1,2,3]      cadena [5 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 1]
```

entonces el valor más lejano en este caso sería el uno y tendría que reemplazar el 5 por el 1 obteniendo este resultado: `[5,2,3]`  `cadena [4 , 3 , 2 , 1]` para luego repetir el procedimiento, pero en este caso el valor 5 no se volverá a usar entonces el resultado sería: `[4,2,3]`

Alguno me podría dar una mano con la lógica de estos problemas?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

*int v= 4;*

```
int[] cadena = new int[v];

for(int i=0; i=v; v--){

 for(int j=0; j<=v; j++){

  System.out.print(cadena[j]);

 }
```

}

No estoy seguro de lo que realmente quieres, pero en principio esto te va mostrando la cadena hasta que deja de existir.

Comment: Sino te sirve lo reviso y te lo rehago

Comment: Creo que esto es JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

Se que lo que estabas necesitando no es exactamente esto, pero... debajo  dejo una implementación del [Algoritmo Óptimo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_reemplazo_de_p%C3%A1ginas#.C3.93ptimo).

> Cada detalle del proceso esta documentado a lo largo del script

```js
function algoritmoOptimo (marcos, paginas) {
  var memoriaLlena = false,
    i = 0,
    valor,
    enMemoria,
    actual,
    anterior,
    candidato,
    candidatos,
    fallos = 0,
    mapaMemoria = {},
    log;

  // LOGs
  document.getElementById('marcos').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(marcos);
  document.getElementById('paginas').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(paginas);
  log = logTiemposHeaders();

  // Inicio de proceso
  paginas.forEach(function(proceso, idx) {

    // Comprobamos que todos los marcos esten llenos
    if (!memoriaLlena) {
      for (; i < marcos.length; i++) {
        valor = marcos[i];

        // Si el marco esta vacio
        if (valor === null) {
          escribirMarco(i, proceso, idx);
          i++;
          return;
        }
      }

      // Si todos los marcos ya esta llenos
      memoriaLlena = i === marcos.length;
    }

    enMemoria = false;
    candidatos = [];
    actual = 0;
    anterior = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < marcos.length; i++) {
      valor = marcos[i];

      // Si ya esta en el marco
      if (valor === proceso) {
        enMemoria = true;
        break;
      }

      // Obtenemos la distancia del proceso en el marco en las paginas restantes
      actual = paginas.indexOf(valor, idx + 1);

      // Si no esta las paginas restantes
      if (actual === -1) {
        actual = paginas.length;

        // Es candidato a fifo
        candidatos.push(i);
      }

      // Si la distancia del proceso en el marco actual en las paginas restantes
      // es mayor o igual a la del proceso anterior 
      if (actual >= anterior) {
        anterior = actual;
        candidato = i;
      }
    }

    // Si ya estaba en memoria
    if (enMemoria) {
      log += logTiempos(idx);
      return;
    }

    // Si hay uno o mas candidatos, es porque hay uno o mas procesos
    // que no se encuentra en las paginas
    if (candidatos.length) {
      anterior = -1;
      actual = 0;
      
      // Para cada uno de los candidatos
      candidatos.forEach(function(posicion) {
        actual = mapaMemoria[posicion];
        // Buscamos aquel que lleva mas tiempo en memoria
        if (actual > anterior) {
          anterior = actual;
          candidato = posicion;
        }
      });
    }
    
    //
    escribirMarco(candidato, proceso, idx);
  });
  
  // LOGs
  document.getElementById('tiempos').innerHTML = log;
  var frecuencia = Number(Number(fallos / paginas.length).toFixed(2));
  document.getElementById('frecuencia').innerHTML = frecuencia;
  document.getElementById('rendimiento').innerHTML = parseInt((1 - frecuencia) * 100, 10) + '%';

  return;

  // ------------------
  // Metodos privados

  function escribirMarco(posicion, proceso, tiempo) {
    // Escribimos el proces en el marco indicado
    marcos[posicion] = proceso;
    // Hubo acceso a disco 
    fallos++;

    marcos.forEach(function(proceso, idx) {
      // Si no esta seteado el contador en el mapa de memoria para la poscion de marco
      if (mapaMemoria[idx] === undefined) {
        mapaMemoria[idx] = 0;
      }
      // Si el contador en el mapa de memoria es igual al que a que acabamos de escribir
      // lo igualamos a 0, en caso contrario lo incrementamos 
      mapaMemoria[idx] = idx === posicion ? 0 : mapaMemoria[idx] + 1;
    });
    
    // Log para generar la tabla de tiempos
    log += logTiempos(tiempo, true);
  }

  function logTiemposHeaders() {
    var html = '<tr><th>Tiempos</th>';

    marcos.forEach(function(proceso, idx) {
      html += '<th> Marco ' + (idx + 1) + '</th>';
    });
    html += '<th>Fallos</th></tr>';
    return html;
  }

  function logTiempos(tiempo, fallo) {
    var html = '<tr><td>Tiempo ' + (tiempo + 1) + '</td>';

    marcos.forEach(function(proceso) {
      html += '<td>' + (proceso === null ? '-' : proceso) + '</td>';
    });
    html += '<td>' + (fallo ? 'X' : '-') + '</td></tr>';
    return html;
  }
}


//
algoritmoOptimo([null,null,null], [4,1,2,5,1,2,3,4,5]);
```

```html
Marcos:
<span id="marcos"></span><br/>
Paginas:
<span id="paginas"></span><br/>
Tiempos:
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="text-align:center; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top">
  <tbody id="tiempos"></tbody>
</table><br/>
Frecuencia de Fallos:
<span id="frecuencia"></span><br/>
Rendimiento del algoritmo:
<span id="rendimiento"></span>
```